# Circumvent "This post seems a duplicate"

Tags: support, asking-questions, exact-duplicates

I changed a small piece of text in my previous question. The alteration is an important one and warrants a separate question.

However, the system decides that I am posting the same question again and the button "Post your question" does not work.

[image]

What to do?

For the time being I appended a dummy text "This question is not a duplicate" to fool the system and was successful in posting the question - [How to type S-<LEFT>](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43734/how-to-type-s-left).

Compare - [How to type C-M](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43733/how-to-type-c-m)

Answer (score 2):

Your question [How to type S-<LEFT>](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43734/how-to-type-s-left) is not actually how to type `S-left` but how to use the transient mode for `indent-rigidly`. If you'd included more information in your title, and if you'd copied the text from the manual instead of a screenshot, the system would probably not have flagged it as a probable duplicate.

Never make a screenshot of text unless you need to show the formatting (e.g. in a question about coloring text), and if you do this, include the text as text as well.